# Изменение объекта, который перетаскивает игрок. (IDragHandler и StandaloneInputModule)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь изменить объект, который перетаскивает игрок.

```
public class DragInputModule : StandaloneInputModule
{
    private static GameObject _draggingObject;
    private static GameObject _replaceDraggingObject;

    public static void ReplaceDraggingObject(GameObject target)
    {
        _replaceDraggingObject = target;
    }
    protected override void ProcessDrag(PointerEventData pointerEvent)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Я сделал свой InputModule в котором переопределил ProcessDrag, но у меня возникла проблема с реализацией метода. Также я нашёл стандартную реализацию этого метода:

```
        if (pointerEvent.IsPointerMoving() || pointerEvent.pointerDrag != null)
        {
            if (!pointerEvent.dragging && ShouldStartDrag(pointerEvent.pressPosition, pointerEvent.position, eventSystem.pixelDragThreshold, pointerEvent.useDragThreshold))
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
                pointerEvent.dragging = true;
            }
            if (pointerEvent.dragging)
            {
                if (pointerEvent.pointerPress != pointerEvent.pointerDrag)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerPress, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
                    pointerEvent.eligibleForClick = false;
                    pointerEvent.pointerPress = null;
                    pointerEvent.rawPointerPress = null;
                }
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void ProcessDrag(PointerEventData pointerEvent)
    {
        if (pointerEvent.pointerDrag == null && _replaceDraggingObject != null)
        {
            pointerEvent.pointerDrag = _replaceDraggingObject;
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
            pointerEvent.dragging = true;
            _replaceDraggingObject = null;
        }
        if (pointerEvent.IsPointerMoving() || pointerEvent.pointerDrag != null)
        {
            if (!pointerEvent.dragging && ShouldStartDrag(pointerEvent.pressPosition, pointerEvent.position, eventSystem.pixelDragThreshold, pointerEvent.useDragThreshold))
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
                pointerEvent.dragging = true;
            }
            if (pointerEvent.dragging)
            {
                if (pointerEvent.pointerPress != pointerEvent.pointerDrag)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerPress, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
                    pointerEvent.eligibleForClick = false;
                    pointerEvent.pointerPress = null;
                    pointerEvent.rawPointerPress = null;
                }
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
            }
        }
    }
```